# phpcassa describe keyspace call on new CF object

Tags: php, cassandra, thrift, phpcassa

Is this call really made every time a new ColumnFamily object is created?
If I cache the response, what would be consequences - assuming the schema does not change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be totally fine. (Incidently, this whole process is made unnecessary for CQL clients [in Cassandra 1.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-2734).)